# How to get the largest number in an array?

Tags: java

I am trying to find the largest number in an array of 10 numbers. Here is my code:

```
public static void getNumber() {
        int NumbersArray[] = new int[11];
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int largestNumber = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter number " + i );
            int no1 = scanner.nextInt();
            NumbersArray[i] = no1;

        }
        scanner.close();

        for(int i=1; i<11; i++)
        {       
            System.out.println(NumbersArray[i]);
            num1 = NumbersArray[i];
            for(int j=10; j>0; j--)
            {
                num2 = NumbersArray[j];
                if(num1>num2){
                    largestNumber = num1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the largest number is " + largestNumber);
    }
```

I found a real simple soultion to this [here](http://www.java-examples.com/find-largest-and-smallest-number-array-example).

But the reason I am posting this is to find out what mistake have I made.
The first portion gets 10 numbers from the users and the second portion is my code to find the largest number.

Comment: You could greatly simplify the code by check which number is largest AS the user is entering the values, doing away with the second/double loop

Comment: It would be easier to explain your mistakes if you would explain how do you think this code works (or should work). What do you think happens in each of your loops?

Comment: just a little sidenote: arrays in java are 0-based. This means the first element in an array is `array[0]`, not `array[1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location of Largest Number in an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660070/location-of-largest-number-in-an-array)

Comment: Just a note. If you are down voting a question please specify the reason for it. Without it you are wasting time. Who ever it is, you are simply making it more difficult for others to use this site. So either mention the reason or stay out of the discussion.

Comment: @RishitShah people have also pointed out issues you have not addressed, it's possible that those are why you have down votes. Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might help you improve your questions. Namely you need to say why you think this code doesn't work, and/or any errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

Going off Pshemo's suggestion, keep a record of the largest int as the user is typing. This reduces the size of your method by half and makes it much simpler and more readable.

Program with 0-based indexing. So use `int NumbersArray[] = new int[10]` instead of `int NumbersArray[] = new int[11]`. When you declare the size of your array, simply put your desired size, you don't have to worry about 0 indexing or anything. For your for-loop, start at `int i=0` and end at `i<10`.

```
public static void getNumber(){
    int NumbersArray[] = new int[10];
    int largestNumber = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter number " + i );
        int no1 = scanner.nextInt();
        NumbersArray[i] = no1;
        if(no1 > largestNumber)
            largestNumber = no1;

    }
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println("The largest number is: " + largestNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are iterating through the list twice (in a nested way). Let's say you have the following numbers: `[5, 7, 3, 4]`. As you go through the inner loop the first time you'll end up comparing numbers against 5. Only 7 is larger so `largestNumber` will be set to 7. Then you'll go through again, this time comparing against 7. Nothing is larger than 7, so it'll be left alone. Next you'll compare against 3. The last comparison there is 3 vs. 4, and since 4 is larger you end up setting `largestNumber` to 4, which is incorrect.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer i was looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
 for(int i=1; i<11; i++)
    {       
        System.out.println(NumbersArray[i]);
        num1 = NumbersArray[i];
        for(int j=10; j>0; j--)
        {
            num2 = NumbersArray[j];
            if(num1>num2){
                largestNumber = num1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Don't search for the largest number in the array, but simply search for any value in `NumbersArray` a value that is bigger than the current element. Thus `largestNumber` isn't the largest number in the array, but the last number in `NumbersArray` that is larger than the last element of `NumbersArray`, unless the last element of `NumbersArray` is the biggest element, in this case the `largestNumber` will be the last value in `NumbersArray`.

A working solution would be:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i : NumbersArray)
    if(max < i)
        max = i;
```

Though the most efficient solution would be to directly keep track of the currently largest input while reading the input.

And keep in mind that java-arrays are **0-based**. This means that the first element is at `NumbersArray[0]`, not `NumbersArray[1]`, like in your code.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer i was looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can use Java Math max() method to get largest number.
i.e. : dataType max(int number1, int number2), Math.max(number1, number2) gets the maximum between number 1 and 2.